# Create record on click rails 5

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

So I have course modules and course module users and I want the user to be able to tick the module when they complete the module.

I have a database table set up for this, however, I only want the record to create in the database record once the tick is clicked.

I have the database table set up like the following:

[image]

So I want this so once the user clicked the tick, the database captures the course_module_id and user_id and also I want it so it marks the module as complete as `true` as it's a boolean.

I have the views and models like so

**View**

```
<% if @course_modules_user.complete! %>
  <i class="fas fa-check text-green float-left mr-1"></i>
  <span class="text-xs mr-2">Completed</span>
<% else %>
  <%= link_to complete_course_module_path(course_module), method: :put do %>
  <i class="fas fa-check text-grey-darkest float-left mr-2"></i>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

**Model**

```
class CourseModulesUser < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :course_module
  belongs_to :user

  def complete!
    self.update_attribute(:complete, true)
  end
end
```

The error I am getting is the following

[image]

So initially the modules look like this

[image]

but once a user clicks the tick I want the record to create and now show like so

[image]

But obviously, I only want to have a record created in that table so I can see who has completed a module and output that data to a user.

Comment: The error you are getting indicates that `@course_modules_user` is nil, it needs setting in the controller, could be a typo. Also should it not be `complete?`, not `complete!`?

Comment: @Kris I don't have a controller for course_modules_user I just want a record to create on click if I need a controller for this I can create one? But course_modules_user is showing in multiple pages, only using `if` statements checking whether it exists.

Comment: I'm just saying the cause of the error. There is some controller which renders the view and it is not setting `@course_modules_user`, since as the error shows it is nil.

Comment: I have tried this in the courses_controller.rb https://gyazo.com/0f4624b47c77dd39f7790de067c7a02d but still no luck, that's the main courses controller

Comment: `@course_modules_user` should reference to a single object, not a collection.